# Google Sheet ARRAYFORMULA with IF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using IF function as below and getting the result, but when I use the same function with ARRAYFORMULA am getting the circulating dependency error:

Without ARRAYFORMULA
`=if(isblank(A2),"",IFERROR(IF(A2<>A2,1,B1+1) ))`

With ARRAYFORMULA `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>A2:A,1,C1:C+1) )`

Further, the result of formula is getting started from cell No. B3, is it possible to get the result started from cell B2 i.e. the cell in which the formula is applied.

Below is the link of the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qLjYukNR1E_vgwqeGutQRtg3H7-3eU2heUPHsqQpg90/edit#gid=1713558709.

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should consider explaining what is your goal: What I have (**input**) VS what I want (**output**), and most likely a complete different approach will be suggested to you

Comment: Best Answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. This array formula can be found in B1 of that sheet:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header"; IF(A2:A="",, ROW(A2:A)-VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),{1;FILTER(ROW(A2:A),A2:A="")},1,TRUE))})`

You can change the header text as you like.

Here is a plain-English interpretation of the rest of the formula: "If a cell in A2:A is blank, leave it empty; otherwise, subtract the row number of the last empty row from the current non-blank row number. If A2 is non-blank, return 1."

Comment: Thanks Erik Tyler....your solution worked perfectly fine....

Comment: Happy to hear it. Would you take a moment to mark the post as "Best Answer"? This helps other contributors know at a glance which issues have been fully resolved; and it helps future site visitors quickly find the most relevant answers.

Comment: Hi. There should be an outline of a checkmark next to my post, visible to you. Click that and it should turn green. That is how to officially mark the post as resolved (and the reply that resolved it as "Best Answer." Thanks.